# How to select data from multiple model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have three model project_manager, project_director, and human_resource each has a status Boolean field how can i print some thing in rails if Boolean value of these three model is true. currently i am accessing data from model by doing this-

```
            <% if project_site.project_managers.empty? %>
              <td class="pending fi-eye"><%= " Pending" %></td>
            <% else %>
              <% project_site.project_managers.each do |project_manager| %>
                <% if project_manager.status == false %>
                  <td class="rejected fi-x"><%= ' Rejected' %></td>
                <% elsif project_manager.status == true %>
                  <td class="approved fi-check"><%= " Approved" %></td>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>

            <% if project_site.project_directors.empty? %>
              <td class="pending fi-eye"><%= " Pending" %></td>
            <% else %>
              <% project_site.project_directors.each do |project_director| %>
                <% if project_director.status == false %>
                  <td class="rejected fi-x"><%= ' Rejected' %></td>
                <% elsif project_director.status == true %>
                  <td class="approved fi-check"><%= " Approved" %></td>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>

            <% if project_site.human_resources.empty? %>
              <td class="pending fi-eye"><%= " Pending" %></td>
            <% else %>
              <% project_site.human_resources.each do |human_resource| %>
                <% if human_resource.status == false %>
                  <td class="rejected fi-x"><%= ' Rejected' %></td>
                <% elsif human_resource.status == true %>
                  <td class="approved fi-check"><%= " Approved" %></td>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
```

i want to print approved if all these three model status value is true how can i do that in rails?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, all you need is something like this:

```
<% if human_resource.status? %>
  <td class="approved fi-check"><%= ' Approved' %></td>
<% else %>
  <td class="rejected fi-x"><%= ' Rejected' %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: hey i want to print  "approved" if project_manager, project_director and human_resource status is true. how can i do that>

Comment: I just wrote how you can do that.

Comment: how can i print if anyone status model in false then "rejected" else "pending" by default status is nil

Comment: hey i am not able to print <tr> in case of human_resource.status.nil

Answer (score 3):

Create a helper method and put the following code :

```
def check_resource_status(project_site, resources)
 statuses = project_site.send(resources.to_sym).pluck(:status)
 statuses.all? ? true : false
end

def status_container(status)
 content_tag :div, class: ['sample'] do
  status_label = status ? 'Approved' : 'Rejected'
  default_class = status ? 'fi-check' : 'fi-x'
  status_class = [default_class, status_label.downcase]
  concat content_tag(:label, status_label, class: status_class)
 end
end
```

From your view file :

```
status_container(check_resource_status(project_site, 'human_resources'))
status_container(check_resource_status(project_site, 'project_directors'))
status_container(check_resource_status(project_site, 'project_managers'))
```